# What does Microsoft Word's "line spacing multiple at" refer to?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, formatting

[image: Paragraph Spacing dialog]

What does it *mean* to have a line spacing multiple at 1.15?

(My font size is 20, however when I compared 1.15 with exactly 23 point, they aren't equal.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means 1.15 times the single line spacing. So for example if the single line spacing was 20 point, the line spacing would be 23 point.

Effectively this gives just a little looser line spacing than the font has been designed for, making for a lighter and less formal look overall.

Comment: my font size is `20`, however when i compared 1.15 with `exactly 23 point` they are not equal. why is that so?

Comment: @Pacerier, the line spacing is not always the same as the font size. It will vary based on the font that is selected.

Comment: @Parcerier, I just tried a slightly different test.  Using the font Calibri, I compared 20pt at 1.15 spacing vs 23pt as single line spacing.  They come out the same size.  20pt seems to have a default line spacing of exactly 24.4pt (22% extra) for this font.

Answer (score 4):

[In Microsoft Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/adjust-the-line-spacing-between-text-or-paragraphs-HP010016523.aspx):

> Line spacing options
>
> **Single**    This option accommodates the largest font in that line, plus a small amount of extra space. The amount of extra space varies depending on the font that is used.
>
> **1.5 lines**    This option is one-and-one-half times that of single line spacing.
>
> **Double**   This option is twice that of single line spacing.
>
> **At least**    This option sets the minimum line spacing that is needed to fit the largest font or graphic on the line.
>
> **Exactly**    This option sets fixed line spacing, expressed in points. For example, if the text is in a 10-point font, you can specify 12 points as the line spacing.
>
> **Multiple**    This option sets line spacing that can be expressed in numbers greater than 1. For example, setting line spacing to 1.15 will increase the space by 15 percent, and setting line spacing to 3 increases the space by 300 percent (triple spacing).

Note:  Line spacing is also known as [leading](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading&ei=jj1LTv7jJ8njiAK-rLF9&usg=AFQjCNEIZtmucF0NV_LkS1hSooxVg1Wb1g).

Answer (score -1):

Multiple values are a bit tricky, and not exactly related with a percentage value; that is, 1.15 does not increase the space by 15%.

Test it yourself: Two columns of text, set in 10 pt, line spaced respectively 12 pt (Exactly) and 1.20 (Multple). Not equal. In this specific case, one need to change the Multiple value to 1.

Comment: The formal description of the field indicates it is based on percentage.  How do you resolve the differences between the formal description of the field to your answer?  The setting is based on the characteristic of the font being used, and based on what the single spacing would be, and is indeed a percentage of whatever that would have been.